# IIS Application Pool Memory Size Problem

Tags: windows, .net, iis-7.5, iis

I increased my application pool memory size from default to 500 mb. and i have IIS 7.5.
My server sometimes falling down (service unavailable) and i don't know the reason. I did couple of changes at the same day that i changed memory size in iis and from that days i am getting this problem in one of my servers.

Is there anybody can tell me what is the right way to increase memory and what can be the problems????

Thankss

Roni

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about the "private memory limit" in advanced options of app pool "recycle" section. (if that assumption is not correct please do precise what exactly did you do to set the "memory size")

When you have changed the limit to 500MB from the default value 0 which means no limit actually, you have created (not increased) a limit that might be causing your problems. If your app requires more memory then app pool limit, then the pool gets recycled..

I would check the system logs to get a better picture of the situation. (which is to be done even if my assumption from the top is incorrect)

Comment: You are right. This is what i mean. But i read lots of articles say that the default memory limit for app pool is 200 mb for iis 7. So that's why i did the change.

Comment: well as I said, **check the system logs** in the time when such a "crash" happened and see what's in there. Alternatively change the limit back to 0, and check whether things still go bad - than you'll be sure it's connected to the memory limit, not something else that you changed (according to what you said, you did some other changes..)